# Python3 - for ROW in fd instead of line

Tags: python

Is it possible to split something by ", " on a row and print it out as a separate line

```
fd = open("data.txt", "r").readlines()

i = 0

for line in fd:
    line = line.lstrip().rstrip().split(", ")[i]
    print("Subject-%d: %s" % (i, line))
    print("Name-%d: %s" % (i, line))
    print("Fruit-%d: %s" % (i, line))
    i += 1
```

Text file contains this:

```
People, Zeref, Apple
Greeks, Zues, Apricot
```

Basically what I want the code to do is split the text file by ", " and print each one onto a new line so it says this

```
Subject-0: People
Name-0: Zeref
Fruit-0: Apple
Subject-1: Greeks
Name-1: Zues
Fruit-1: Apricot
```

For some reason it just says

```
Subject-0: People
Name-0: People
Fruit-0: People
Subject-1: Greeks
Name-1: Greeks
Fruit-1: Greeks
```

Comment: `.lstrip().rstrip()` is surely exactly equal to `.strip()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
line = line.lstrip().rstrip().split(", ")[i]
```

This line splits the line by comma and takes the i'th element (it works for i=0,1 and probably 2 but you'll get an exception once i will be bigger)

What you would actually like to do is -

```
subject, name, fruit = line.lstrip().rstrip().split(", ")
```

And then print each variable but a more elegant way would be to use [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: We can use strip() only instead of lstrip() and rstrip() both.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't currently work, is because in the example you give, you are taking a fixed item per line (`line = ...[i]`) where `i` does not change in between you printing the different lines.

Assuming your file always contains the same structure `Subject, Name, Fruit`, I would use `zip()` to loop over the line:

```
fd = open("data.txt", "r").readlines()
labels = ['Subject', 'Name', 'Fruit']

for line_num, line in enumerate(fd):
    line = line.lstrip().rstrip()
    for label, item in zip(labels, line.split(', '):
        print("%s-%d: %s" % (label, line_num, item))
```

Additionally, I would replace your print statement with a 'more modern' version:

```
print(f'{label}-{line_num}: {item}')
```

or if you work in a version < 3.6

```
print('{}-{}: {}'.format(label, line_num, item)
```

but that is mostly personal preference.